# i am not access contact on my phone pleas suggest how can i resolve this problem

Tags: contacts

There is a contact in my contacts which can't be found by name in dialer, but if type her number in the dialer the name appears.

Comment: More details kindly. Are you using the default contact app? A different contacts app does this happen with that particular contact only.

Answer (score 0):

I once experienced similar problem. I did the following:

1) Deleted the contact

2) Hard reset (press the button near SIM card slot until phone vibrates).

3) Added the contact agian after the reboot.

This worked for my phone, but I'm not sure if its universal solution.